# cakephp - How can I update a record using Hash class function

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am new to CakePhp and want to Update record. 
I have successfully fetched records from my table.

```
$SQL = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Table WHERE Id = '123';
return Hash::combine($this->query($SQL), '{n}.{n}.Id', '{n}.{n}');
```

Above code returns records properly.

Table Name: Table__c 
Model Name: Table.php 
Controller Name: TablesController.php

I have tried following:

```
$sObjects = array();
$sObject = new stdClass();
$sObject->Id = 123; 
$sObject->Name = "abc";
array_push($sObjects, $sObject);
$result = $this->Table__c->save($sObjects);
```

which gives me error: *Call to a member function save() on a non-object*

Earlier I was using Salesforce and following code was fine:

```
$this->query(array('update', $sObjects, 'Table__c'));
```

But with MySQL it gives me error:
*SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty*

Comment: Any specific reason why you're avoiding using the framework's default way of [saving entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-entities)?

Comment: I recommend you to read the book, especially the tutorial, from the beginning instead of doing trial and error -> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html What you do simply doesn't make any sense within the scope of the framework.

Comment: @Oldskool I have working CakePHP application with Salesforce database and same table name. Now I want to shift to MySQL and because some other Services are linked to these tables I am not suppose to change table name or any php file name. Please suggest me some solution if you have for above question.

Comment: @tejas033 You can still use the same tables, you don't *have* to rename them to follow Cake convention. See [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage). Simply set `$this->table('table_name');` in your Table object's initialize method and Cake will use that table. You can set up a read-only access if you need and write anything to another Table if you don't want the systems to interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your comments I appreciate that.

**Answer:**

If your table name and model name do not match by adding in your model class:

```
var $useTable = 'Table_Name';
```

you can use that table.

Now how are you going to update record in this table:

```
    $sObject = new stdClass();
    $sObject->Name = "'abc'";
    $sObject->Address = "'xyz'";

    $condition = array('Id' => "123");

    $this->updateAll((array)$sObject, $condition);
```

updateAll() function will update records matching the `$condition`